# If I use a voltage multiplier will the output wattage be less than the input wattage?

Tags: high-voltage

A step up transformer steps up voltage and the wattage stays the same from the primary to secondary. Does a Cockcroft Walton generator or Marx generator work this way too? On the full wave Cockcroft Walton generator there’s a capacitor on each AC source lead, so to me it looks like it blocks a lot of wattage, please explain why. Does the half wave Cockcroft Walton generator able to transmit a higher wattage than the full wave Cockcroft Walton generator? Also in the half wave Cockcroft Walton generator does it only transmit half the voltage, so if I had a 15 kV AC source would that only transmit 7.5 kV through the first stage, or would it multiply the full 15 kV?

The Marx generator it looks different. There’s no capacitor blocking the leads. While using this will the output wattage be different from the input wattage?

Should I use one or the other? I’m trying to multiply my voltage but retain the full wattage on the output from what was input. It makes no sense to me. someone please clarify. I want my voltage to be in the millions and also to retain my full wattage.

Also, since I want such a high voltage I could also build my own step up transformer but I don’t know what the limits of a step up transformer are. I’ve seen X-ray transformers go up to 320 kV. That’d be good for a voltage multiplier, but couldn’t I just make my own transformer so I could get 1000 kV or even 1200 kV on the secondary or will a turn ratio that high have significant power losses?

[image]

Comment: The Marx generator converts DC to a higher DC, but only in pulses.  The Cockcroft-Walton converts AC  to a higher DC.

Comment: Output power is always less than input power in a continuous system. You always have losses in any energy conversion or transfer. The laws of energy conversion and thermodynamics always apply.

Comment: So will it ever output the full wattage minus the little system losses you guys are talking about or is it more of a spark show toy that uses and output very low wattages?

Comment: Pulse power can be greater than continuous power. But not for very long.

Comment: I think you are asking whether the circuit has inherently limited wattage, is that correct? You mean that the capacitance in a Cockcroft-Walton generator inherently limits the power output and no matter how much power is available at the input or how low the load impedance is, you can't get more than a certain amount from the output without redesigning the generator, right?

Answer (score 4):

You need to distinguish between fundamental limitations, and practical limitations. Practically, all converters will deliver less output power than they take to run. However, some converters will lose more than others. Basically components that get hot in a converter are losing some of the input power.

With a resistively connected Marx generator for instance, the initial RC charging, if done by connecting the input to a voltage source, will immediately lose 50% of the charging energy as heat in the resistors. This is fundamental to the use of resistors for connection. If instead the stages are connected with inductors, and charged from a suitable current-output converter like a flyback, there will be no fundamental losses. In both cases, there will be the additional practical losses of efficiency of the power supply, voltage drop across the spark gaps, series resistive losses everywhere, electromagnetic radiation etc, etc.

In a Cockcroft-Walton, the series capacitors do not 'block wattage' as such, they transfer the input AC's peak to peak voltage swing to later stages, LESS the charge that they lose operating the later stages. As each stage has to drive all the succeeding stages, this appears as an output impedance that goes as the number of stages squared.

There's an interesting case with the voltage doubler (2 stage Cockcroft-Walton) used in microwave ovens, where the input capacitor impedance is neutralised by making the power supply transformer deliberately have a high leakage inductance.

Answer (score 0):

If the wattage remains the same depends solely on devices which consume real power.If you have devices which consume real power then the output wattage cannot be the same with the input wattage.

Comment: Can you give an example of a diode that **does not** consume real power? I think your answer is misleading because you imply that it might be possible to construct a voltage multiplier with magical components that don't consume power.

Comment: I am not implying that diodes dont consume real power.I just say in general due to conservation of energy if there are devices which consume real power the output wattage will be less than the input wattage.